# Vertically center border on paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center a border around the 'about' div class containing the 3 paragraphs. The border is too high, I want to move it down to vertically center it. I can adjust the height but I can't move the border down at all.

```
<div class='about'>
<p>
JavaScript (/ˈdʒɑːvəˌskrɪpt/[5]) is a high-level, dynamic, untyped, and interpreted programming language.
</p>
<br>
<p>
Despite some naming, syntactic, and standard library similarities, JavaScript and Java are otherwise unrelated and have very different semantics.
</p>
<br>
<p>
JavaScript is also used in environments that are not web-based, such as PDF documents, site-specific browsers, and desktop widgets.
</p>
<br>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.about {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 200px;

}
```

It is difficult to visualize what I need without looking at the complete code on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/njh5scyd/

Please help! Been trying to figure this out...

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You should do this with `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements:

```css
/*main.css*/

html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, div, p, ul, ol, li {
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 70px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 200;
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 1px solid white;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h2 strong {
 font-weight: 500;
}

.tagline {
 padding: 15px 0 25px 0;
 width: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.links ul li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.links {
 text-align: center;
}

.links a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.about {
 width: 500px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.about:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  content: '';
}

.about:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class='header'>
    <h1>Daffy Duck</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class='tagline'>
    <h2>fdsfsdfsdfsdfds <strong>fewfwefwef</strong> fdsfdsfsdf <strong>sdfdfsf</strong></h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class='links'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='file:///Users/Frank/Desktop/moee.html' target='_self'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='file:///Users/Frank/Desktop/javascrip.html' target='_self'>Portfolio</a></li>
            <li>Resume</li>
            <li><a href='file:///Users/Frank/Desktop/game.html' target='_self'>About</a></li>
            <li>Why Me</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class='about'>
<p>
JavaScript (/ˈdʒɑːvəˌskrɪpt/[5]) is a high-level, dynamic, untyped, and interpreted programming language.[6] It has been standardized in the ECMAScript language specification.[7] Alongside HTML and CSS, it is one of the three essential technologies of World Wide Web content production; the majority of websites employ it and it is supported by all modern web browsers without plug-ins.
</p>
<br>
<p>
Despite some naming, syntactic, and standard library similarities, JavaScript and Java are otherwise unrelated and have very different semantics. The syntax of JavaScript is actually derived from C, while the semantics and design are influenced by the Self and Scheme programming languages.
</p>
<br>
<p>
JavaScript is also used in environments that are not web-based, such as PDF documents, site-specific browsers, and desktop widgets. Newer and faster JavaScript virtual machines (VMs) and platforms built upon them have also increased the popularity of JavaScript for server-side web applications.
</p>
<br>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a fixed height of `200px` on your `.about` element. Unless you have a definite purpose for it, you should remove it. If you do that your `.about` element will extend naturally and wrap around the content inside it properly.

That will naturally affect your border, which is directly tied to your `.about` element. The height of your `.about` has a direct relationship with your border, which surrounds the `.about` element. Smaller height than the content? Smaller height of the border as well.

Let me know if you have any questions or need anything further from this point on.

```css
html {
  background-color: black; /* added for testing purposes only */
}
.about {
  color: white; /* added for testing purposes only */
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='about'>
  <p>
    JavaScript (/ˈdʒɑːvəˌskrɪpt/[5]) is a high-level, dynamic, untyped, and interpreted programming language.
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
    Despite some naming, syntactic, and standard library similarities, JavaScript and Java are otherwise unrelated and have very different semantics.
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
    JavaScript is also used in environments that are not web-based, such as PDF documents, site-specific browsers, and desktop widgets.
  </p>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just draw the borders on `<p>` and drop these `<br>` : https://jsfiddle.net/njh5scyd/3/

```
.about {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;

    }
  .about p {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    padding: 15px;
    margin:0;
  }
```

---

`background-image/background-size` can help to tune this as well : https://jsfiddle.net/njh5scyd/4/

```
.about {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom, white, white) center right no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(to bottom, white,white) center left no-repeat;
  background-size: 1px 60% ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. just change `.about`'s style like below:

```
.about {
width: 500px;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 50px;
/*border-right: 1px solid white;
border-left: 1px solid white;*/
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
/*height: 200px;*/
 position:relative;
}
```

Then put new styles below.

```
.about::before,.about::after{
  content:" ";
  width:1px;
  height:200px;
  top:calc(50% - 100px);
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  background:#FFFFFF;
}
.about::after{
  right:0;
  left:initial;
}
```

Check my live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/njh5scyd/2/)